# MySQL - sort by date column which is stored as text in format MMYYYY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to sort by a column called `date` which stores various dates in format `MMYYYY` (for example, `122020`, `102019`, etc.).

The SQL query that I have looks like this:
`` SELECT `date`, `invested` FROM `savings` WHERE `id` = 123 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date`, "%m%Y") ASC `` but this query does not sort the output correctly.

Any ideas on how to sort it properly?

**Important note:** Reclassifying/modifying the column's type is not an option at this point.

**EDIT:** My current SQL query, which is described above, sorts the dates like this: 102019, 102020, 112019, 112020. But my goal is to have it like this: 102019, 112019, 102020, 112020.

Thank you

Comment: Can you pls elaborate with examples where your current solution sorts incorrectly? Your pattern for string to date conversion fits the date format described in your question, so we will need additional clarification.

Comment: Can you please share something as  a screenshot from the database and also datatypes of your table structure you have created. Please provide more options as it's' not clear. Thanks

Comment: ```ORDER BY `date` MOD 10000, `date` DIV 10000```. *but this query does not sort the output correctly* Of course, incorrect date value produces NULL for all rows.

Comment: *Reclassifying/modifying the column's type is not an option at this point.* What about adding generated column into the table structure?

Comment: For example, my current SQL query, which is described in my question above, sorts the dates like this: 102019, 102020, 112019, 112020. But my goal is to have it like this: 102019, 112019, 102020, 112020.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the date string into two parts (year and month), cast each part as integer, and then ordering by that number:

```
SELECT 
    date_, 
    invested 
FROM 
    savings
WHERE 
    id = 123
ORDER BY 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(date_, 3, 6) AS UNSIGNED),
    CAST(SUBSTRING(date_, 1, 2) AS UNSIGNED)
;
```

This will do the job :) refer to this [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pENjBcvSxA4UFTBnRD6GgN/0) for clarification.